# SaveEventually withCallback

Tags: parse-platform

Will ParseObject.saveEventually(SaveCallback cb) populate the parse object's object id before calling the callback's "done" method? There is nothing about this in the documentation and although I could experiment with trail/error, it wouldn't guarantee anything in all cases or in the future.

My usecase is to minimize web calls as much as possible and so I'd much rather grab the object ID on completion instead of having to call back to parse on completion to pull down the data if it's already available.